# Renaming of site column „Enterprise Keywords“ without risk?

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, site-column

I would to rename the site column „Enterprise Keywords“ (that can be added to content types so that users are able to tag items) to “Tags”. 
This is possible, but my question is: Do you have experience if renaming this site column can somehow lead to problems later?
Or is it possible without risk?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on individual lists/libraries no problem. You aren't changing the internal name or any of the connections, just the display name. I've done this without problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but i wouldn't just do this on indiviudal lists/libraries. I would rename the complete site column in a content type hub. Do you also have experiences with that ?

Comment: Nearly everything in SharePoint references using internal names, which you can't change - this is how SharePoint works multi-lingually.